# Decode Grails URL params correctly?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

In my GSP I have something like:

```
<head>
  <meta property="og:image"
    content="${createLink(controller:'main', action:'getImage', id:item.id, params:[width: 115, height:200], absolute : true)}" />

</head>
```

When I look into the code that is generated I found:

```
<meta property="og:image"
    content="http://www.myurl.com/main/getImage/faf878ef93996f26c1?width=115&amp;height=200" />
```

The problem with this is that there is some **amp;** value inside.

In my Controller:

The params look like this:

```
[width:115, amp;height:200, id:faf878ef93996f26c1, action:getImage, controller:main]
```

The problem is that params.height is not working anymore since there is the amp; again.

How do I decode this url correctly? Is there a way that Grails does not place the amp; inside the url?

When I do the following in my GSP body:

```
<body>
  ${createLink(controller:'main', action:'getImage', id:item.id, params:[width: 115, height:200], absolute : true)}"
</body>
```

I get the correct url:

http://www.myurl.com/main/getImage/faf878ef93996f26c1?width=115&height=200

Why does Grails sets these urls different? How to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know is this question still actual, but somebody may stuck with this problem. So solution is wrapping link generated code into raw() function:

```
<meta property="og:image"
content="${raw(createLink(controller:'main', action:'getImage', id:item.id, params:[width: 115, height:200], absolute : true))}" />
```

However encoded url will work too. usually this property used to display image when llink to website shared somewhere. So services can handle and decode it normally

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are rendering your link as a string within the gsp, so grails encodes it before printing it out. You don't even have to have a link, just try

"${m&m}" and you will see that grails renders that out as m&amp;m

One solution would be to use the direct rendering, which I believe bypasses the additional encoding in grails

```
<% out << '<meta property="og:image" content="' + createLink(controller:'main', action:'getImage', id:item.id, params:[width: 115, height:200], absolute : true) + '" />' %>
```

Comment: This is not working I got: <sitemesh:captureMeta gsp_sm_xmlClosingForEmptyTag="/" property="og:image" content="....

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off default encoding for that specific page as well.

Put following at the top of gsp page

```
<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>
```

Comment: This is not working. I get the same result. Any other suggestions?